# QGIS Relation reference widget performance

Tags: qgis, postgis, relation

I have a relation 1:1 on a table with limited parcels (ca 2000 rows) related to huge table on national level (ca 22 million rows), PostgreSQL 14 with PostGIS. Smaller table is used with view to show geometries from the national scale table. Relation columns on both sides are indexed and attribute table and rendering works perfectly without special widgets on columns.
I would need to use the functionality of `Relation reference` widget to open parent record, but mainly to use `On map identification` as show below.

[image]

I can edit the form with identify feature correctly and make use of `On map identification` . It's working as expected until I open the attribute table of the smaller one. The table doesn't open and QGIS is stacking memory indefinetly. Seems like the `Relation reference` widget is querying the other table as whole hence overloading QGIS and memory.
I have tried `Use read-only line edit instead of a combobox` but it doesn't help.
I don't need to look up the table from the reference, but I would need to use the map identification widget.
Seems it should work but I need the widget to stop scanning the parent table id when I open the child (smaller) attribute table.

[image]

Anyone knows some setup to overcome this behaviour on the widget? Or it should be addressed to QGIS issues?

*Versions: QGIS 3.22.11 LTR, PostgreSQL 14.5, PostGIS 3.2.3*

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to ask a question.